How to Implement a SCEP Proxy/Gateway as a Middleman Between CA Server and Devices with Compliance Checks?
I have a solution where Android devices contact a SCEP server directly to obtain identity certificates, using code written in jscep and Bouncy Castle. For iOS, we leverage the native support provided by the OS via the SCEP payload to retrieve certificates. However, I’ve encountered the following challenges in the current setup:
Challenges in the Current Setup
Security Concerns with SCEP:
Devices typically use a global passcode. If this passcode is leaked, any device could generate certificates, leading to security vulnerabilities.
Lack of Compliance Checks:
There is no verification of device compliance during the certificate generation process, which raises concerns about unauthorized devices obtaining certificates.
Protocol Support Variability:
OS-level support for certificate enrollment protocols like SCEP and ACME varies, and issues may arise if CA servers utilize other protocols such as EST.
Proposed Solution: SCEP Proxy/Gateway
To address these issues, I am considering implementing a SCEP proxy/gateway, similar to solutions provided by competitors such as:
JAMF: https://learn.jamf.com/en-US/bundle/technical-paper-scep-proxy-current/page/Overview.html
SecureW2: https://www.securew2.com/blog/using-a-scep-gateway-to-distribute-certificates-to-managed-devices
The goal is to have a proxy that performs device compliance checks and improves security. However, I have a few questions about the best way to implement this.
Key Implementation Questions:
Should the SCEP proxy be an HTTP server that performs device compliance checks before allowing certificate generation?
If so, what would be the best way to structure these checks?
How should I handle the static/dynamic challenge part?
Should the proxy handle the challenge itself and then embed it into the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) before forwarding it to the SCEP server?
How should the proxy handle security (tokens/shared secrets)?
Should I implement token-based authentication, or use a shared secret between the device and proxy, as SecureW2's gateway does? Would this help ensure that only compliant and authorized devices can interact with the proxy?
What should the interaction flow between devices and the proxy look like?
My aim is for devices to continue making SCEP calls (e.g., scep.enroll) and interacting with the proxy as if they were directly contacting a real SCEP server. Should the proxy handle the entire SCEP process and pass only verified requests to the actual SCEP server?
Goal:
I'm looking for guidance on how to implement the SCEP proxy/gateway for my use case, ensuring it performs compliance checks, handles challenges securely, and seamlessly interacts with devices as a  SCEP proxy.
